# Using MongoDB C# Driver write ElementMatch with Regex query

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongo-shell

I need to construct the following query using MongoDB C# driver

```
db.Notes.find({ "Group._id" : 74, "CustomFields" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Value" : /batch/i } }, "IsDeleted" : false }).sort({ "CreatedDateTimeUtc" : -1 })
```

I used a query like this

```
builder.ElemMatch(x => x.CustomFields, x => x.Value.Contains(filterValue))
```

It generated mongo query as

```
db.Notes.find({ "Group._id" : 74, "CustomFields" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Value" : /batch/s } }, "IsDeleted" : false }).sort({ "CreatedDateTimeUtc" : -1 })
```

if you notice it is appending s at `/batch/s` instead of i `/batch/i`

How can I get this work? I need to do this for filters like

1. **contains**, using .Contains()
2. **equals**, thinking of using .Equals()
3. **doesn't contain**, thinking of using !Field.contains(value)
4. **not equals to**
5. **starts with**
6. **ends with**

Can I do something like this, so that I can apply all my regex patterns for all above filters.

```
builder.Regex(x => x.CustomFields[-1].Value, new BsonRegularExpression($"/{filterValue}/i"));
```

This converts the query to as below, but that doesn't get any results

```
db.Notes.find({ "Project._id" : 74, "CustomFields.$.Value" : /bat/i, "IsDeleted" : false }).sort({ "CreatedDateTimeUtc" : -1 })
```

FYI: `builder` is `FilterDefinition<Note>`

My sample Notes Collection is like this:

```
{  
   Name:"",
   Email:"",
   Tel:"",
   Date:02   /21/1945,
   CustomFields:[  
      {  
         Name:"",
         Value:"",
         IsSearchable:true,

      },
      {  
         Name:"",
         Value:"",
         IsSearchable:true,

      },
      {  
         Name:"",
         Value:"",
         IsSearchable:true,

      },
      {  
         Name:"",
         Value:"",
         IsSearchable:true,

      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like all you're missing is the insensitive part. Have you tried this?

> ToLower, ToLowerInvariant, ToUpper, ToUpperInvariant (string method)
>   These methods are used to test whether a string field or property of
>   the document matches a value in a case-insensitive manner.

According to the 1.1 documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/linq/), it says that will allow to perform a case insensitive regex match.
The current documentation doesn't mention it, so just to be sure, i checked github and the code to create an insensitive match is still [there](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/21e8768c964b37ed9f8b0039efdadff71fc465b3/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs).

Comment: insensitive part is one and I also need to write query where text begins with, text ends with and text doesn't contain. I think I can only do such things with BsonRegularexpression?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that as part of the question. The mongo driver will correctly handle a `String.StartsWith()` and `String.EndsWith()`, turning them into `/^` and `$/` respectively. it should also turn a unary not `!` into a mongo `$not: { }`

Comment: how about "does not contain" search?